# Node.JS kernel mode threading

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to figure out how does Node.JS (of its Windows version) is working behind the scenes.

I know there is user mode and kernel mode threads, and I know the processing model looks like this:

[image]

I also know that moving from a kernel mode thread to a user mode thread is consider to be a context switching.

Does Node.JS C++ Non-Blocking worker threads are kernel mode ? and where does the single event loop thread lives at kernel mode or user mode ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As you know node.js has a single threaded architecture. The JavaScript environment and event-loop is managed by a single thread only, internally all the other threads are handled by a C++ level thread pool (like asynchronous I/O handled by libuv thread) .

To answer your question these node.js C++ non-blocking worker threads are not kernel mode. They are user mode. The event-loop thread is also user mode. The threads request kernel mode as and when needed.

When the CPU is in kernel mode, it is assumed to be executing trusted software. Kernel mode is the highest privelege level and the code has full access to all devices. In Windows, only select files written by Windows developers runs completely on kernel mode. All user mode software must request use of the kernel by means of a system call in order to perform privileged instructions, such as process creation or I/O operations.

All processes begin execution in user mode, and they switch to kernel mode only when obtaining a service provided by the kernel. This change in mode is termed mode switch, not context switch, which is the switching of the CPU from one process to another.

I hope it is clear to you that even user-mode threads can execute privileged operations (network access) via system calls, and return to user-mode when required task is finished. Node.js simply uses system calls.

Source : http://www.linfo.org/kernel_mode.html

#### Update

I should have mentioned that mode switch does not always mean context switch. Quoting the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch):

> When a transition between user mode and kernel mode is required in an
> operating system, a context switch is not necessary; a mode transition
> is not by itself a context switch. However, depending on the operating
> system, a context switch may also take place at this time.

What you mention is also correct that mode switch can cause context switch. But it does not happen always. It is not desirable to have context switches (heavy performance penalty) whenever mode switch happens. What happens inside Windows is difficult to say, but most likely mode switch does not cause context switch every time.

Regarding the one-to-one thread model. Both Windows and Linux follow that. So given each user thread (like node.js event loop thread) OS provides a kernel thread, which takes care of the system calls. Node.js can only invoke mode switch through system calls. Context switch is controlled only by the kernel (thread scheduler).

#### Update 2

Yes, HTTP.SYS executes in kernel mode. But there is more to it. Node.js does not have many threads, so fewer context switching happens between threads unlike IIS. Context switch (mode switch) for each request is definitely less in HTTP.SYS. It is an improvement from past (which happened to be a disaster), see [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaushal/archive/2013/05/27/difference-in-iis-6-iis-7-x-and-iis-8-with-regards-to-ssl.aspx). The context switching due to multiple threads is much more than reduction of context switch by using HTTP.SYS. So overall node.js has less context switches.

HTTP.SYS also has other advantages over node's own HTTP implementation that helps [IIS](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/introduction-to-iis/introduction-to-iis-architecture). It may be possible (in future) to use HTTP.SYS from node itself to take those advantages. But for now, I don't think HTTP.SYS/IIS compete anywhere near node.js.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer.
you've mentioned: "..This change in mode is termed mode switch".
I've read here http://programming4.us/website/2606.aspx that:
"Context switches occur when a running thread and privileged (kernel) mode to use an Executive or subsystem service.".

From what you are saying, node isn't doing any context switches, right ?

I've also read that in Linux environment, there is only one-to-one threading model (kernel mode). So does node perform differently ?

Comment: *perform differently under Linux ?

Comment: @ohadinho added the explanation

Comment: Thanks, and very last question: Is it true that IIS receives requests through HTTP.SYS which works kernel mode, and then sends them to I/O thread (user mode) which post it to the CLR ThreadPool (also user mode) which returns it to HTTP.SYS --> So there are many context switches. And on the other hand, Node.JS works only user-mode so there aren't any context switches ?

Comment: "Context switch (mode switch) for each request is definitely less in HTTP.SYS".. 
why is that ? with Node, Request is being held in user-mode only (event-loop thread and a threadpool thread). with IIS, is goes to HTTP.SYS thread, afterwards to I/O user mode thread, then to ThreadPool user mode thread, and back to the HTTP.SYS thread.

Comment: Think on per request basis. For HTTP.SYS each request will have two context switches (mode switch) so that it is processed by worker thread. For node it can be upto mode switches(don't know for sure how many) plus context switches equal to the number of threads in thread pool. I was considering worst case scenario in my answer - requiring all the threads, each request maynot go through the whole thread pool in reality. And certainly it does not for most of the requests. In my Windows PC the node.js has 4 threads (including event loop).

Comment: So the difference is actually the number of WORKER threads.. The IIS uses one thread per request from the ThreadPool, and in Node we don't know how many threads it uses from the TreadPool, right ?
And another question, we can limit the number of IIS threads in the Machine.config, and you have mentioned that Node has less threads - so it has less context switching between request threads. If we would limit the thread number of the IIS, it will perform the same as Node (If we would work Async completly in the ASP.NET application) ?

Comment: Is there a context switching between the event-loop thread and the
ThreadPool thread when the first is sending the request to the second ?

Comment: Yes but this does not happen every time. There is a subtle advantage in sending, it queues the requests, when sent (they are events). So many requests can be picked up. And many events can be processed in the queue, when context switch happens.

Comment: To your previous question yes, it would but it needs not just async execution but event driven architecture too (event loop in its HTTP.SYS).

Comment: Thanks! And a very last question: HTTP.SYS is multi-threaded or single-threaded ?

Comment: If you want to know if HTTP.SYS internally uses kernel level thread pool or not then no. IIS which uses HTTP.SYS is multi-threaded.

Comment: "These node.js C++ non-blocking worker threads are not kernel mode."
Do you have any docs/evidence that prove that?

From what I can see in libuv, the threads there are not yielding in IO like DNS. It looks like kernel threads to me.